# ProgressDialog displays incorrect

Tags: android, progressdialog

I try to implement progressDialog in my application, here me code:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
pd.setTitle(R.string.creating_a_gif);
pd.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.preprocessing));
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
float duration = (float) (mModel.getGifEndPosition() - mModel.getGifStartPosition());
int totalFrames = (int) ((duration / SECOND_IN_MILLIS) * mModel.getFps());
pd.setMax(totalFrames);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
    ctx.getString(android.R.string.cancel),
    (dialogInterface, i) -> FFmpeg.getInstance(ctx).killRunningProcesses());
pd.show();

mBuilder.setProgressListener((f, ft) -> {
  pd.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.frames_processed));
  pd.setIndeterminate(false);
  new Thread(() -> {
    pd.setProgress(f);
    pd.setSecondaryProgress(f);
  }).start();
});
mBuilder.setCompleteListener(pathToGif -> {
  pd.dismiss();
  goToPreview(pathToGif);
});
```

When this code is performing first time during one app session, my progress dialog miss his paddings like this:
[image]

and all next times my code performs dialog is okay:

[image]

What can I do to display my progress dialog correctly always?

Answer (score 0):

Change to `pd.setIndeterminate(false);`

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
pd.setTitle(R.string.creating_a_gif);
pd.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.preprocessing));
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
float duration = (float) (mModel.getGifEndPosition() - mModel.getGifStartPosition());
int totalFrames = (int) ((duration / SECOND_IN_MILLIS) * mModel.getFps());
pd.setMax(totalFrames);
pd.setIndeterminate(false); //<--- change to false
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
    ctx.getString(android.R.string.cancel),
    (dialogInterface, i) -> FFmpeg.getInstance(ctx).killRunningProcesses());
pd.show();

mBuilder.setProgressListener((f, ft) -> {
  pd.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.frames_processed));
  pd.setIndeterminate(false);
  new Thread(() -> {
    pd.setProgress(f);
    pd.setSecondaryProgress(f);
  }).start();
});
mBuilder.setCompleteListener(pathToGif -> {
  pd.dismiss();
  goToPreview(pathToGif);
});
```

Comment: sorry, but it does no helped me :( turning this option to false jsut disables progress bar aniimation until some part of work started

Comment: Please share all java file

Comment: there is no need to to this, all code bound with progress listener is attached already

Comment: progressDialog becames without padding before anny progress